# Exact meaning of compactly supported smooth function - support can be any measurable compact set?

Tags: real-analysis, smooth-functions

Let $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the space of compactly supported smooth function on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Here, I am now a bit curious about the precise meaning of support and smooth.

For example, any measurable $B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ of finite measure can be approximated by compact subsets.

Let's say $K_m \subset B$ is compact and $\mu(B-K_m) < \frac{1}{m}$ for each $m \in \mathbb{N}$, where $\mu$ is the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure.

Then, I remember vaguely that there exists a smooth function $\phi_m : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ supported on $K_m$ for each $m \in \mathbb{N}$.

However, $K_m$ can be quite arbitrary and even discrete. In all such cases, how does one define smoothness?

Could anyone please clarify for me?

Comment: A compactly supported function is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$, so we just use the usual notion of smoothness. "Compactly supported" just means that it is zero outside of a compact set (a bit more precisely, the closure of $\{x:f(x)\not=0\}$ is compact).

Comment: I am particularly concerned about the cses where the support is discrete.

Comment: Also, I would like to make sure that for any compact measurable set $K$, there indeed exists a smooth function supported on $K$. Is this true?

Comment: The claim you're asking about is not true: in order for there to be a smooth function whose support is $K$, $K$ must be appropriately nice. In particular, since smooth implies continuous, $K$ can't be discrete (and so your particular concern doesn't arise).

Comment: That is where I am confused. Because on discrete sets, you can impose the discrete topology to define continuity and so on..

Comment: But this is all living in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the usual topology. That's what the notation "$C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$" indicates.

Comment: Yes, as the subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$, a discrete subset has the discrete topology..

Comment: To tell whether $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is in $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, we do two things: (1) check whether $f$ is smooth in the usual $\mathbb{R}^n$-sense and then (2) check whether $cl(\{x:f(x)\not=0\})$ is compact (again in the usual $\mathbb{R}^n$ sense). Neither of these steps is ambiguous. Note that step (1), where we check smoothness, **does not refer to the support at all**.

Comment: Maybe a  example could help: $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1,\quad x=0;\\ 0,\quad |x|\geq 0;\\\frac{1}{1+\exp\left(\frac{1-2|x|}{x^2-|x|}\right)},\ \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments above, it seems you're misparsing "smooth function with compact support" as "function with compact support which is smooth on its support." This is **not** what it means: the requirements for $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ to be in $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ are precisely that

- $f$ be smooth in the usual $\mathbb{R}^n$-sense, and
- $cl(\{x:f(x)\not=0\})$ be compact (also in the usual $\mathbb{R}^n$-sense).

In particular, the support of such an $f$ can never be discrete since for any smooth (or even continuous) $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ the set $\{x: f(x)\not=0\}$ will be open. In order to be the support of a continuous (let alone smooth) function, a compact set $K$ must satisfy $$K=cl(int(K)).$$ It's a good exercise to check whether this necessary condition is also sufficient.